# Wrong plot in pfgplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot a function in a LaTeX document. Usually I use either Mathematica, Matlab or Root. At this point I want to use `pgfplots` in order to keep my document in a complete LaTeX layout. The thing is that `pgfplots` doesn't produce the exact plot as Mathematica, let alone the weird thing that's going on with the `y-axis`.

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$d\sigma$}
  ] 
    \addplot[blue,domain=0:pi]{1-sin(x/2)^2}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

while Mathematica gives

[image]

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Use `\addplot[blue,domain=0:3]{1-sin(deg(x/2))^2};`. It needs degrees.

Comment: @percusse: Thank you very much for your answer! You are absolutely right! Thank's alot! Would you mind answering the question, so as to accept you answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First, the domain `1:2*pi` means the interval [1, 2pi]. In Mathematica, you asked for the interval [0,pi]. So replacing `1:2*pi` by `0:pi` should give you the correct interval to draw.

The second problem is that the `sin` function expects an argument in degrees, not radians. To convert from radians to degrees, you can use the `deg` function. Replacing `sin(x/2)` by `sin(deg(x)/2)` will do the trick.

Manually overriding the minimum/maximum x and y values, and removing the frame can be done by setting the appropriate options. The following code produces more or less the same plot as your Mathematica plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ 
    xmin=0, xmax=3.4,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.1, 
    axis lines=left,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel={$d\sigma$}
  ] 
    \addplot[blue,domain=0:pi]{1-sin(deg(x)/2)^2}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank yuo very much for your answer! About the first part, you are right! I found it out and while you were answering I was editing y code! About the second part, Thank you!!!!

Comment: Is there a way to plot the `x-axis` in degrees and a legend?

Comment: Yeah sure. Change the domain to `0:180` and remove the `deg` again.

Comment: To convert from radians to degrees, you may use `x/2 r` instead of `deg(x)/2`.